# Is there a way to create a scope and inject dependencies into the scope?

Tags: simple-injector

I need that scopes are scoped to some instance (imagine an `HttpContext` instance) and to inject services into that scope (imagine `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse`).

Than I would do something like:

`container.Register<HttpContext>(myScope);
container.Register<HttpRequest>(myScope);
container.Register<HttpResponse>(myScope);`

**Edit1**,**Edit2**

Can I do this?

```
container.Register<IDependency, MyHttpContextDependency>();
container.Register<IService, ExternalService>();
```

where:

```
public class ExternalService : IService
{
    public ExternalService(IDependency dependency)
    ...
}

public class MyHttpContextDependency : IDependency
{
    public MyHttpContextDependency(HttpContext httpContext)
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I image HttpContext, I see the WebRequestLifestyle. This lifestyle will be automatically scope instances around HttpContext. If that doesn't work, please add more details to your question.

Comment: I understand how `WebRequestLifestyle` will scope instances around `HttpContext`. But can it resolve `HttpContext` as a dependency? See **Edit1**.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from registering HttpContext in Simple Injector, but you shouldn't because HttpContext is runtime data and you [shouldn't inject runtime data into your application components](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: Don't be too literal, @Steven. It's not literally `HttpContext`. I need it for runtime context. It's like a child container. But, keeping with the `HttpContext` allegory, how would I do it?

Comment: Can you improve your question to supply more details, what you want and ehy you want it. What kind of context do you want? Where do you store it? Why do you need child containers? Why does creating an AsyncScopedLifestyle or ThreadScopedLifestyle not work?

Comment: I need my scope to inject some dependencies. If I can't, all my registrations will be factories that create instances based on the supplied context.